# We need to design std::list with added features

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

I am aware that std containers are not meant to be inherited because of absence of virtual destructors. So, I have used std::list as a private member. I need help on the iterator of this class.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __pk_DList_h__
#define __pk_DList_h__

#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
class DList {
public:
DList() { }

DList(int size, T val) { list_(size, val); }

int size() { return list_.size(); }
//typedef list<T>::iterator Iterator;
class   iterator {
public:
iterator(T *p = nullptr) : p_(p) {}
    //operator T*           () { return p_; }
T&      operator*               () { return *p_; }
    //list<T>::iterator operator->  () { return  p_; }
void    operator++              () { if (p_) p_ = p_->next(); }
bool    operator==              (const iterator & rhs) { return p_ == rhs.p_; }
bool    operator!=              (const iterator & rhs) { return p_ != rhs.p_; }
private:
T*  p_;
};


std::list<T>::iterator begin() { return list_.begin(); }
std::list<T>::iterator end() { return list_.end(); }

void pushFront(T elem) {
    list_.push_front(elem);
}
void pushBack(T elem) {
    list_.push_back(elem);
}

void popBack() {
    list_.pop_back();
}

void popFront() {
    list_.pop_front();
}

T back() {
    list_.back();
}

T front() {
    list_.front();
}

bool empty() {
    return (list_.size() > 0)?false:true;
}
private:
std::list<T> list_;

DList(const DList &s) {}

void operator=(const DList &s) {}
};

#endif //__pk_DList_h__
```

I want to use this class like this..Any help with the iterator would be appreciated. I am struck with only iterator part. I need an example of how to implement this inner class iterator in DList class.

```
DList<int> myList;
myList.pushFront(12);
myList.pushBack(13);
myList.pushBack(15);
for (std::list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++) 

{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Comment: Except for the unusual spelling of the members, how does your class differ from `list` ? The biggest problem I have with `typedef list<T>::iterator Iterator;` is the capital I.

Comment: if you are planning to return the `list<T>::iterator` from your `begin()/end()` members, then you don't need to implement your own iterator

Comment: if you have to have your own iterator, have a [look at this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daed815b4e47cf76)

Comment: The only difference I can see is slightly different names (camel case mostly), `front` and `back` return copies of elements, and a crude attempt to block copy assignment and move?  And an extra copy in the length/value ctor?  I see no added features.  `iterator` type you define is never used, but unused code is not an "added feature".

Comment: *"I am aware that std containers are not meant to be inherited because of absence of virtual destructors"* - There's a subtlety here you are missing. Inheriting from `std::list` is a bad idea if you intend to use it polymorphically (pass your type where a `std::list&` or `std::list*` is expected, and that place deletes it). Inheriting is perfectly okay for code re-use if you use your new type in a non-polymorphic setting only.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Does it iterate? Even if DList just uses std::list<T>::iterator, you may want to hide std::list entirely, so also hide its iterator type. Return DList<T>::iterator (which happens to be identical to std::list<T>::iterator, at the moment). Same for public typedefs like value_type, difference_type, etc. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list. Unit test with some std algorithms, like std::sort, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @sp2danny ...That part works fine. However I was trying to understand what is std::bidirectional_iterator_tag? Never come across this one before.

Comment: @Yakk There would be some added functionalities which are not implemented as of now. This is just to see how iterator works.

Comment: @AnkitSaha It's a tag, ie an empty type, used for dispatch, that is to help select algorithm based on iterator category. see [tag dispatch](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/examples/overloading-tag-dispatch/)

Comment: @ankit But you haven't told us what is wrong with the above implementation.  The above code iterates.  Do you want to know how to iterate not using `std::list<T>::iterator` directly?  There is no **question here**.